# Error while deploying jar in weblogic

Tags: java, web-services, ejb, weblogic

**An error occurred during activation of changes, please see the log for details.**

> Message icon - Error Exception preparing module:
>   EJBModule(Demo_web_service) [EJB:011023]An error occurred while
>   reading the deployment descriptor. The error was: Error processing
>   annotations: . Message icon - Error There are 1 nested errors:
>   weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.AnnotationProcessException: [EJB:015002]Unable to
>   load class com.cms.webservice.CMSWebServiceBean in Jar
>   D:\Aswin\Demo_web_service.jar : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   Class bytes found but defineClass()failed for:
>   'com.cms.webservice.CMSWebServiceBean'
>
> > Message icon - Error Exception preparing module:
> >     EJBModule(Demo_web_service) Unable to deploy EJB: Demo_web_service.jar
> >     from Demo_web_service.jar: There are 1 nested errors:
> >     java.io.IOException: JDT compilation error! at
> >     weblogic.ejb.container.ejbc.CompilerForJDT.compile(CompilerForJDT.java:66)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.ejb.container.ejbc.EJBCompiler.doCompile(EJBCompiler.java:358)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.ejb.container.ejbc.EJBCompiler.compileEJB(EJBCompiler.java:556)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.ejb.container.ejbc.EJBCompiler.compileEJB(EJBCompiler.java:523)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.runEJBC(EJBDeployer.java:441)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.compileJar(EJBDeployer.java:766)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.compileIfNecessary(EJBDeployer.java:666)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.prepare(EJBDeployer.java:1241)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.prepare(EJBModule.java:427)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:391)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:59)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:43)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:1221)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:367)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:39)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:207)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:98)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:157)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:12)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:45)
> >     at
> >     weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:516)
> >     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201) at
> >     weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173) Message icon -
> >     Error JDT compilation error!

Can you please help me out to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Class bytes found but defineClass()failed for` error indicates you have a Java mismatch. Weblogic is running with a different JDK/version of Java than the compiled war file you are deploying.

See: [Class bytes found but defineClass()failed for error when deploying EAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771470/class-bytes-found-but-defineclassfailed-for-error-when-deploying-ear)