# Class bytes found but defineClass() failed for error when deploying EAR

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic, version, jdeveloper

I have create ear in my project in JDK 1.7_79 and Jdeveloper JDK  is pointing to 1.7_81. Not able to have the exact version of JDK. Can someone reolve this.
I am getting the error while deploying through weblogic em console

JDK 1.7_79 is the correct JDK version but i am using only 1.7_81 it should work or not ??

[September 11, 2019 6:31:16 AM EDT] weblogic.utils.ErrorCollectionException:

There are 1 nested errors:

weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.AnnotationProcessException: [EJB:015002]Unable to load class JBBean in Jar AR_V4.2.0/opy0wb/model.jar : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class bytes found but defineClass()failed for: 'cclass BEan'

Comment: Does it really say `Class bytes found but defineClass()failed for: 'cclass BEan'`?

Comment: I have checked in Jdeveloper , where there are two placed we can change the JDK version :-

1.  jdeveloper\jdev\bin\jdev.conf where you can update the JDK version and then restart the jdeveloper and you check in the about of jdeveloper.

2. It's in the porject properties > compiler  > changing the JDK version of source files and JDK files.

Comment: The JDK version is probably irrelevant here, as there's only a difference of 2 micro versions. I'm still wondering about `'cclass BEan'`. Is that your typo or is it really in the error message?

Comment: Kayaman u can assume as a className any example class , has to hide the actual class Name

Comment: Probably due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771470/class-bytes-found-but-defineclassfailed-for-error-when-deploying-ear). You didn't indicate the Java version that Weblogic uses.

Comment: I tried the second  example of updating the JDK from project properties to 1.7 .

after deploying to em console I am getting this error. 
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:  com/avocent/trellis/apps/process/artifacts/geeservice/CategoryQuery :

Comment: how can i check the weblogic version @Kayaman . it's Just the Browser error not the stack trace .

Comment: The stacktrace (as well as anything interesting) is in the server's logs of course. The `UnsupportedClassVersionError` shows you the version of the classfile you're trying to load. If it's 1.7, then you're running on 1.6 or lower, and so on.

Comment: com/avocent/trellis/apps//getmachinecateservice/Machine : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 will give the full stack trace as well